# Shutdown Debian after closing other process

Tags: linux, bash, debian, shutdown

I am making a very simple environment in Debian 9:

- Debian launches
- Automatic login takes places
- Nano launches immediately
- User saves the file and closes nano
- When nano is closed, automatic shutdown takes place

How can I automatically shutdown Debian immediately after closing nano?

(Sorry for my english, btw)

Comment: How is nano launched?

Comment: What happens if nano crashes, or is suspended, or killed by something other than the user? Already tried `nano && shutdown`?